# Use optimize.minimize from scipy with 2 variables and interpolated function

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I didn't find a way to perform optimize.minimize from scipy with a multidimensional function. In nearly all examples an analytical function is optimized while my function is interpolated. The test data set looks like this:

```
x = np.array([2000,2500,3000,3500])
y = np.array([10,15,25,50])
z = np.array([10,12,17,19,13,13,16,20,17,60,25,25,8,35,15,20])
data = np.array([x,y,z])
```

While the function is like F(x,y) = z

What I want to know is what happens at f(2200,12) and what is the global maximum in the range of x (2000:3500) and y (10:50). The interpolation works fine. But finding the global maximum doesn't work so far.

The interpolation

```
 self.F2 = interp2d(xx, -yy, z, kind, bounds_error=False)
```

yields

```
<scipy.interpolate.interpolate.interp2d object at 0x0000000002C3BBE0>
```

I tried to optimize via:

```
x0 = [(2000,3500),(10,50)]
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(self.F2, x0, method='Nelder-Mead')
```

An exception is thrown:

```
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

I think that the optimizer can't handle the object from the interpolation. In the examples the people used lambda to get values from their function. What do I have to do in my case?

Best,
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to find global maximum (instead of minimum) you need to interpolate your function with opposite sign:

```
F2 = interp2d(x, y, -z)
```

Second, the callable in `minimize` takes a tuple of arguments, and `interp2d` object needs input coordinates to be given as separate positional arguments. Therefore, we cannot use `interp2d` object in `minimize` directly; we need a wrapper that will unpack a tuple of arguments from `minimize` and feed it to `interp2d`:

```
f = lambda x: F2(*x)
```

And third, to use `minimize` you need to specify an initial guess for minimum (and bounds, in your case). Any reasonable point will do:

```
x0 = (2200, 12)
bounds = [(2000,3500),(10,50)]
print minimize(f, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds)
```

This yields:

```
  status: 0
 success: True
    njev: 43
    nfev: 243
     fun: array([-59.99999488])
       x: array([ 2500.00002708,    24.99999931])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     jac: array([ 0.07000017,  1.        ,  0.        ])
     nit: 43
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and comments! It works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

One more possible solution (hope you get the idea):

One more function is created (f), and the minimized values are sent as arguments to this function.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

x = data.Height.values
y = data.Weight.values

def f(params):
    w0, w1 = params
    return mse(w0, w1, x, y)

optimum = minimize(f, (0,0), method = 'L-BFGS-B', bounds = ((-100, 100), (-5,5)) )
w0 = optimum.x[0]
w1 = optimum.x[1]
```

Also tried implementation with lambda function, but had no luck.