# Lambdifying functions of multiple variables

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I am trying to optimize a cost function EL_c

```
EL_c=-300.49858410695*C_0 - 301*C_1 - 60.2000000000003*C_2
```

After confirming the free variables by using

```
EL_c.free_symbols={C_0,C_1,C_2}
```

I have tried to use

```
ff=lambdify(("C_0","C_1","C_2"),EL_c)
```

and then

```
x0=(1,1,1)
scipy.optimize.minimize(ff,x0,method="Nelder-Mead")
```

However, I get the error

```
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'C_1' 
and 'C_2'
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to optimize the function using the above method.

Comment: I guess you just need to change  the call to minimize: don't put the variables for the lambda in a tuple, just drop them in minimize: `scipy.optimize.minimize(ff, 1, 1, 1, method="Nelder-Mead")`

Comment: I have tried that but I got 
    'minimize() got multiple values for argument 'method''

Comment: Hhm, well that's bad ... i think the a slightly hacky option would be to give the lambda a tuple containing the three variables but i guess that's not the plan here :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation of optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), which was pointed out correctly in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37523030), the callable function that's being optimized must accept a **tuple of shape (N,)**, not simply N arguments.

What worked for me was:

```
ff = lambdify((A,B,C), EL_c)
fff = lambda x: ff(*x) # Unpack tuple into positional args
scipy.optimize.minimize(fff, x0=(1,1,1), method="Nelder-Mead")
```

(My variables were called A,B,C.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer that has worked. By any chance do you know how I could add constraints to limit A,B,C between -1 and 1 ?  I used 

con0=x[0]+1 
con1=1-x[0]
con2=x[1]+1 
con3=1-x[1]
con4=x[1]+1 
con5=1-x[1]

cons = ({'type':'ineq', 'fun': con0},{'type':'ineq', 'fun': con1},{'type':'ineq', 'fun': con2},{'type':'ineq', 'fun': con3},{'type':'ineq', 'fun': con4},{'type':'ineq', 'fun': con5})

Comment: @TriposG Check again the documentation of optimize I linked. For some optimization methods there are ways to specify bounds and/or constraints.